# Can I change the type of a custom RSF field?

Tags: custom-field, account

I have a custom field under Account that we've been using for a while, and I need to change it from Roll-Up Summary to Decimal. I cannot see that option when trying to edit the field. Is it possible to make this change in Salesforce?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is 'nope'

You will need to create a new field for the Decimal, then use DataLoader to migrate the current RSF values into the new Decimal field (if you want to preserve them).  Then you can delete the RSF field

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, the new field wizard, on the first step, where it lists all possible types to choose from, the page is segmented in to several sections. You can freely change the type of a field to any other one in the same segment. Data loss is still possible when changing types, but you'll get a warning about destructive changes.